# Сессии в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Нужно закрыть доступ к некоторым страницам и кнопкам сайта, сайт сделан на движке WordPress. Доступ будет открыт только тем пользователям, которые введут некий код, который они получат.

Как закрыть страницу или кнопку, когда сессия не запущена, и открыть на 24 часа после того, как пользователь ввел код?

Comment: А если в мета-данные пользователю писать дату ввода кнопки? Тогда закрыть кнопку/страницу можно будет просто проверкой: если дата_ввода + сутки больше текущей даты, то показываем, иначе скрываем